# React- MaterialTable - How to Color all data column based on header text

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I created in react component MaterialTable with data.
The problem is that i want to color column text based on header text.
for example, I want to color column named "Info" and to color all data under this header in orange color.
Is there a way to this?

[image: MaterialTable]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of the component like this:

```
<Component style={{ color: 'red' }} />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/react/showreact.asp?filename=demo2_react_css_inline

Comment: React component :                                                                                            
            <MaterialTable 
                title={this.getTitle(title)}
                columns={this.getHeaders(table_key)}
                data={this.getRows(table_key)}
                options={utilsOptions().setOptions()}
            />
  The data should be filtered with header condition? how style is doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at their documentation on styling: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling

Comment: Thanks. I made some adjustments accordingly to documentation and it works:).if (key === 'info') 
                return {
                        title: titleValue, 
                        field: fieldValue, 
                        cellStyle:{
                            backgroundColor: '#039be5',
                            color: '#FFF'
                        }
                }

Answer (score 0):

just custom style the rows and column according to your requirements

```
const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
  head: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white
  },
  body: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 14
  }
}))(TableCell);

const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover
    }
  }
}))(TableRow);

// Function / Class

// return 

 <StyledTableCell style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }} align="right">  text <StyledTableCell/>
```

here is my sandbox exmple for you ==>>>
[1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-n6rtt?file=/src/App.js